# How can I download the image but not display it? Using Fresco

Tags: java, android, fresco

I need to save the encoded image to the external storage, to display it later, even if the device is offline.

Comment: Why would you use Fresco for this, instead of `HttpURLConnection`, OkHttp, etc.?

Comment: I need to save a large list of images, the best way seems to be to save all those already coded images to only display in a drawee later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the imagepipeline directly, see http://frescolib.org/docs/using-image-pipeline.html

For example, if you want to prefetch the image to disk cache, you can use something like

```
imagePipeline.prefetchToDiskCache(imageRequest, callerContext);
```